# Full text search query on a specific folder via CMIS

Tags: 2013, cmis, containspredicate

SharePoint 2013 : My CMIS repository's `QUERY` capability is `BOTH SEPARATE`.

With CMIS queries I am unable to use the `CONTAINS` clause and `IN_FOLDER` clause together in the CMIS query for full text search the in SharePoint documents

Is there any way to run a `CONTAINS` query on a specific folder in SharePoint? (through a Java program)